# Why does Add or Copy command in dockerfile not adding a new file

Tags: docker, file, command

I have to add a new file to a running container using Dockerfile.
I tried below steps in the dockerfile
steps in docker file-
ADD updates/abc.txt /temp/abc.txt
ADD updates/abc.txt /temp/abc.txt

Docker file step is failing  and I am getting the below error while building docker image-
Step 5/7 : ADD updates/abc.txt /temp/abc.txt
no such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: Maybe /temp doesn't exist? Try /tmp instead.

Comment: Is updates/abc.txt file available with proper permissions?

Comment: Is that really a space between the two filenames? Replace it by typing the key on your keyboard.

Comment: Is updates/abc.txt file available with proper permissions?-Can you elaborate this ?